# CI pagination not working

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I want to use pagination in CI but when i click on links i get the error invalid argument supplied for for each. I get a category id from link by get method.
The first link is working but when I click it again, it doesn't work. Here is my link:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('forum/topic')?>?t_id=<?php echo $topic->t_id; ?>&cat_id=<?php echo $category->cat_id ?>"><h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $topic->topic_title ?></h4></a>
```

i don't know why its not working. please guide me 
here is my controller

```
public function categories()
{
     $cat_id = $this->input->get('cate',TRUE);
     $data['cat_id'] = $cat_id;
     $data['categories_list'] = $this->mod_forum->categories_list();
     $count = $this->mod_forum->record_count_sort($data);

     $data['categories_pic'] = $this->mod_forum->categories_pic($data);


    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/forum/categories?cat=$cat_id";
    $config["total_rows"] = $count->num_rows();
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config["cat_id"] = $cat_id;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["topics_sort"] = $this->mod_forum->fetch_sort_category($config["per_page"], $page,$config["cat_id"]);

    $data["sort"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('navi');
    $this->load->view('forum/category_content',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');

}
```

this is my model

```
public function record_count_sort($data) {
    return $this->db->get_where('topics',array('cat_id'=>$data['cat_id']));
    }

    public function fetch_sort_category($limit, $start,$cat_id) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get_where('topics',array('cat_id'=>$cat_id));
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

this is my view

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?php
        foreach ($topics_sort as $topic ) {?>
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-left media-middle">
                <a href="">
                  <img class="media-object pull-left" src="" alt="">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body">
                <a href=""><h4></h4></a>
                <a class="orange" href=""></a>
              </div>
            </div>          


        <?php }
         ?>
 <div><?php echo $sort; ?></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: does not look like loaded pagination library?

Comment: What is "$this->input->get('cate',TRUE);" a typo?

Comment: If the pagination wasn't loaded, the error would be different I think.

Comment: <a class="forum" href="http://localhost/shakzee/index.php/forum/categories?cate=1">
     <div>
     Codeigniter    </div>
   </a>

Comment: this is category where and i am using it in where class

Comment: In your $cat_id variable you get 'cate' from the url: `$cat_id = $this->input->get('cate',TRUE);` but in your config your set your base url to: `$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/forum/categories?cat=$cat_id";` Where 'cat' is in the url, not 'cate'. Maybe this is what @Craig was saying?

Comment: Your problem is in your model, but in fetch_sort_category() function. It should return an array or an object, but it doesn't. To be sure, do print_r($topics_sort ) in your view. Then continue from there.